# Jquery code to find duplicates from an array

Tags: jquery, json

i have a json data .

```
data ={{"id":"10","name":"test"},{"id":"10","name":"test1"},{"id":"11","name":"tsst"},{"id":"41","name":"jhkj"},{"id":"11","name":"yuyyu"},}
```

from the json data i am fetching the id to get `location` from a database table as follows

```
data.each(function( index ) {
    var id = index.id //gets 10
                       //again gets 10 and again doing db operations for same id value 
    //db operations 
      //get location details from db using this id    
    // operations after getting locations....................

    });
```

my proble is `id` is repeated ie `10,10,11,41 ,11`.so calling `db` operations for repeated values also.How can i avoid by calling db operations for repeated id values .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var temp = {};
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++ ){
    var obj = data[i];
    if(temp[obj.id] >= 0){
        data.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
    temp[obj.id] = i;
}
console.log(data)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fMRZd/)

Answer (score 2):

Check for duplicate ID may solve your problem.

For Example:

```
var dup= {};
data.each(function( index ) {
    var id = index.id;
    dup.push(id);
    if (dup[id])
        $(this).remove(); //OR DO nothing
    else
     //Your DB Operation

});
```

Comment: You forget to add the tested ID's from `data` to the `dup` array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to avoid to call DB operations for all id in the loop. Just pass everything to backend and get data for all id which you need within one DB operation.

Answer (score 0):

Create another array and add the value in it after checking that it exists or not.

you can use inArray ref : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ for this purpose.